# Заменить список в коде на список в файле

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как эту часть кода заменить, что бы список слов не вписывать ручками в коде, а записывались бы в список из файла .txt

```
        badWords = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
            {
                { "слово1", new List<string>() },
                { "слово2", new List<string>() },
                { "слово3", new List<string>() },
            },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, например так:

```
badWords = File.ReadLines("badwords.txt").ToDictionary(w => w, w => new List<string>());
```